# Why img is not aligning to the baseline of div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a single div to make a navbar with image and ul. **There is a condition that I can't use flexbox or grid display**. I am trying to make it from the basics that I learned till now.
Issues I am getting:

1. Image is getting aligned to the top. Why it is not coming on the base of its div?
2. Without making two divs, Can **I align ul and image vertically at the center in a single div**?

I know there will be much better ways to do this, but I want to get a basic understanding that what is actually happening.

Here is HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="left">
        <img
          src="https://www.qousqazah.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/features-of-a-business-logo.png"
          alt=""
          id="logo"
        />
      
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="right">This is right</div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS Code:

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
}

.left img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border:2px solid pink;
    width: 200px;
}

.left ul {
    border:2px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.left ul li {
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.left ul li a{
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid green;
    top: 8px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

And Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7r4jb8qu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
.left img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;  << instead of baseline
    border:2px solid pink;
    width: 200px;
}

.left ul {
    border:2px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;               << added
}
```

and it works: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4v9p1hLa/)

Note that with `inline-block` also spaces will be displayed. SO

```
<img
  src="https://cdn.magenest.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Magento-Logo-768x327.jpg"
  alt=""
  id="logo"
/>
          <<< this will create unwanted whitespace between the elements
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
```

Comment: Ohk I didn't know about the default behavior of ul. Now, I came to know that ul add some default margin at the top. Thanks!

Comment: @AkashChhabra always use your browser inspector in cases like this. Most elements have a default margin which can break your design. Moreover, inspector has a lot more features that help you find fix bugs in your code. Start using today!

Answer (score 0):

The image **is** aligned to the baseline. But the gap is due to the bottom margin of `ul`. So, remove the culprit from your code.

```css
ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this make image **block** and margin auto

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
}

.left img {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border:2px solid pink;
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}

.left ul {
    border:2px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.left ul li {
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.left ul li a{
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid green;
    top: 8px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="left">
        <img
          src="https://cdn.magenest.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Magento-Logo-768x327.jpg"
          alt=""
          id="logo"
        />
      
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="right">This is right</div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```